# Mass And Gravity (Gravity between Moon and Earth)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

Well I'm still a beginner at the gravity between huge masses ... and the gravity of masses

So what i have learned for now is Kepler's 3 laws , and the equations that i have learned are these

$${T^2}/{R^3} = GmM/R^2 = 4\pi^2/GM$$

So I was solving some questions and one of the questions was ,

Moon Circulating around the Earth the R=384,000Km and T=27.3 Days and Mass=$7.35 * 10^{22}$ find the mass of the earth with these information ...

So it's supposed to be $T^2/R^3 = 27.3^2/384,000^3 = (G*7.35*10^{22}*M)/384,000^2$

another way $T^2/R^3 = 27.3^2/384,000^3 = 4\pi^2/GM$

But after Solving the Equation many times I don't get the Right answer!

Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

$GmM/R^2$ is the gravitational force between two objects. It is not used with Keplar's third law. In fact, Keplar's laws were discovered before the formula for gravitational force was discovered. The equation you want to use is
$$\frac{T^2}{R^3} = \frac{4\pi^2}{GM}$$
where $M$ is the larger mass--Earth in your problem. Also, you need to convert the orbital period (27.3 days) into seconds.

Comment: You can also express $T$ in (Earth) years, $R$ in astronomical unit (AU) and $M$ in solar masses (with in this case $G=4\pi^2$), namely the orbital period of the Moon is roughly 0.0748 years, its radius is roughly 0.00257 AU and the mass of the Earth is roughly 0.000003 solar masses.